# django extra views with CreateWithInlinesViews rendering in template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

let's say, I have following django code......

***views.py***

```
from extra_views import CreateWithInlinesView, UpdateWithInlinesView, InlineFormSetFactory


class ItemInline(InlineFormSetFactory):
    model = Item
    fields = ['sku', 'price', 'name']


class ContactInline(InlineFormSetFactory):
    model = Contact
    fields = ['name', 'email']


class CreateOrderView(CreateWithInlinesView):
    model = Order
    inlines = [ItemInline, ContactInline]
    fields = ['customer', 'name']
    template_name = 'order_and_items.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return self.object.get_absolute_url()
```

and in the html template:

```
<form method="post">
  ...
  {{ form }}

  {% for formset in inlines %}
    {{ formset }}
  {% endfor %}
  ...
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Now the problem is: I need both inlines i.e. ItemInline and ContactInline in different section of html code within a single template. What should the  solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Use **Counter** within a **foorloop** in template.

```
<form method="post">
  ...
  {{ form }}

  {% for formset in inlines %}
      {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
            Item:
           {{ formset }}
      {% elif forloop.counter == 2 %}
           Contact:
           {{ formset }}
  {% endfor %}
  ...
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```